# upload html input file in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i want upload multi images from html field, here is view code :

```
   <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple id="file"/>
```

and my problem is in controller , as every yii2's developer knows these codes for upload file in simple way :

```
        $model->logoFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logoFile');
        $model->logoFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->logoFile->name);
        $model->logoImage = $model->logoFile->name;
```

but in my case the images did not come from yii fields liks this one :

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>
```

so any idea how can i fix my controller to be get multi images and save if in server as well

Note : my tamplate is advanced .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : inside your view, you are using plain html file upload, with name `file`

I will suggest , to change it in yii2 way like this

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'logoFile[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'class' => 'btn btn-default '])->label("Attachment"); ?>
```

also take care of variable used inside view and model

**Model**

```
//public $logoFile;
public function rules() {
        return [
            [['logoFile'], 'file', 'maxFiles' => 4],
]
```

}

**Controller**

```
 $model->logoFile = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'logoFile');

 foreach ($model->logoFile as $file) {
    $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
}
```

Comment: still i faced an issue with save images, i didn't find in folder

Comment: update your question with new code (your view, model and controller code), so we can review and also check for the folder permissions.

Comment: sorry, it's was a bug from my old code, 
thanks a lot, it's working perfectly

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('file');
```

returns array of files sent with input field named "file".

Comment: i could  not find any thing in folder either in db .